# "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized" error when authenticating as server with certificate generated using BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, security, ssl, certificate, bouncycastle

I'm trying to create a certificate using the BouncyCastle.Crypto dll, which is then used to authenticate a SslStream as the server in a Windows Service process, which runs under the Local System account.

However when I get to the SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate) call, it throws a Win32 exception with the error message "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized".

There are several questions on here about this error message, but none of them seem to describe, or solve, my particular problem.

In the hope that someone may be able to offer some help, I include the code I am using to create and install the certificate:

```
// First create a certificate using the BouncyCastle classes
BigInteger serialNumber = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = GenerateKeyPair();

X509V1CertificateGenerator generator = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();
generator.SetSerialNumber(serialNumber);
generator.SetIssuerDN(new X509Name("CN=My Issuer"));
generator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Today);
generator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Today.AddYears(100));
generator.SetSubjectDN(new X509Name("CN=My Issuer"));
generator.SetPublicKey(keyPair.Public);
generator.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WITHRSA");

Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = generator.Generate(
    keyPair.Private, SecureRandom.GetInstance("SHA1PRNG"));

// Ok, now we have a BouncyCastle certificate, we need to convert it to the 
// System.Security.Cryptography class, by writing it out to disk and reloading
X509Certificate2 dotNetCert;

string tempStorePassword = "Password01"; // In real life I'd use a random password
FileInfo tempStoreFile = new FileInfo(Path.GetTempFileName());

try
{
    Pkcs12Store newStore = new Pkcs12Store();

    X509CertificateEntry entry = new X509CertificateEntry(cert);

    newStore.SetCertificateEntry(Environment.MachineName, entry);

    newStore.SetKeyEntry(
        Environment.MachineName,
        new AsymmetricKeyEntry(keyPair.Private),
        new [] { entry });

    using (FileStream s = tempStoreFile.Create())
    {
        newStore.Save(s, 
            tempStorePassword.ToCharArray(), 
            new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()));
    }

    // Reload the certificate from disk
    dotNetCert = new X509Certificate2(tempStoreFile.FullName, tempStorePassword);
}
finally
{
    tempStoreFile.Delete();
}

// Now install it into the required certificate stores
X509Store targetStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
targetStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
targetStore.Add(dotNetCert);
targetStore.Close();
```

Ok, now I have created and installed the certificate. I then configure my Windows Service to use this certificate by supplying it with the generated certificate's thumbprint. I then use the certificate like this:

```
// First load the certificate
X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 certInStore in store.Certificates)
{
    if (certInStore.Thumbprint == "...value not shown...")
    {
        certificate = certInStore;
        break;
    }
}

SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(socket, false), false);

// Now this line throws a Win32Exception 
// "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized"
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate);
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be here?

I don't get the problem if I install a certificate created with 'makecert', but that isn't suitable for production certificates.

I've also tried creating a separate x509v1 CA certificate and then x509v3 certificate for server authentication, but I get the same error, so I removed this in the example code for simplicity.

Answer (score 105):

That particular error message rings a bell. I'll guess that either you did not store the private key with the certificate, or, the Windows service does not have access to the private key. To check this, open the Certificates MMC snap-in:

1. Run mmc (e.g. from the Start menu)
2. File menu > Add/Remove Snap-in
3. Select "Certificates" in left pane and then click Add
4. Select "Computer Account" (for LocalMachine) then click Next,
   and then Finish

Navigate to the certificate and double-click in the right pane. On the General tab that comes up, you should see a little key icon at the bottom, along with the text, "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate." If not, that's the problem. The private key was not saved.

If the private key *is* present, click Ok to dismiss this dialog, and then right-click on the certificate in the right pane and select on the pop-up menu: All Tasks > Manage Private Keys. In that dialog, make sure that the Windows account that the service runs under has read access to the private key. If it doesn't, that's the problem.

Edit: Oops, you wrote that the service runs as Local System, so it must be a missing private key, if it is one of these two problems. I'll leave the key access check in my answer anyway, for anybody else that hits this and is not running as Local System.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it is one of these problems - I definitely have a private key corresponding to the certificate (I can see the icon and text you describe). I tried going into the "Manage Private Keys" dialog and granting Everyone Full Control for the certificate but I still get the same error.

Comment: Check this answer and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322560/certificate-problem-with-a-new-machine-credentials-supplied-to-package-not-rec

Comment: Another thing to try is add the third X509KeyStorageFlags parameter to your 'new X509Certificate2(...)', e.g. X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet, just to make sure everything is lined up correctly when you save it to the store.

Comment: I just today hit this error (same error message, at least) for a certificate that had a private key showing in the MMC snap-in. I deleted it and re-imported it from the snap-in and then it worked. Try deleting the certificate and importing it from a pfx file format using the MMC snap-in, and see if that avoids the error.

Comment: +1 for "All Tasks > Manage Private Keys" (and choosing IIS_IUSRS).

Comment: Had this same issue for a asp.net core site running in service fabric, I had to add Network service though

Comment: Those first 4 steps can be achieved by pressing the Windows key and typing "Manage computer certificates" or enough characters for the option to show up, and then pressing Enter

Comment: Almost nine years later, and this answer is still spot on! (read access to private key was missing)

Comment: How to get the read access?

Comment: In MMC, right-click the cert and select Manage Private Keys... from the menu. Give everyone full control.

Answer (score 44):

Sometime the problem happens when the application try to reach the certificate doesn't have enough privilege to access the certificate, the issue may resolve by running the application as administrator.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice, this burnt me a few months back, and burnt me again today, and this answer helped on both occasions.

Comment: This is exactly correct in my case: Start Visual Studio in Admin mode =) Should be awarded correct answer ;-)

Comment: Or make sure the terminal you run `dotnet run` from is started as administrator.

Answer (score 23):

I've the same issue, tried everything from many posts, and google researching.
But looks like I found fix.
When I changed **Identify** from **ApplicationPoolIdentity** to **LocalSystem** everything start working perfectly.

May be will be helpful for someone.

Comment: It's applicable if you're using IIS. BTW, seek the _Identify_ property in the _Advanced Settings_ of the pool ([official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities))

Answer (score 10):

For me works on Windows Server 2012 R2 (.net 4.6.1) - "All Tasks > Manage Private Keys" and set access to Everyone (setting to IS_IUSRS was not enough)

Comment: FYI, your "not enough" tip was enough for me. :) I right-clicked on my certificate > All Tasks > Manage Private Keys, and added the "IS_IUSRS" group you mentioned and it started working for me.

Comment: Thanks ! That was exactly my issue. I added the user running the windows service which was using the certificate

Answer (score 8):

*Found this solution online but I can't find the source to give the credit.*

Since I ran into the "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized" problem with AuthenticateAsClient() (for client verification), I'd like to document how I solved it. It's a different method with the same end goal. Since it might be useful for AuthenticateAsServer(), figured why not.

Here I convert a BC Certificate to a .NET certificate. Add an extra step in converting it to a .NET X509Certificate2 to store it's PrivateKey property.

```cs
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bcCert;

X509Certificate dotNetCert = DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(bcCert);
X509Certificate2 dotNetCert2 = new X509Certificate2(dotNetCert);
```

Problem showed up when adding a BouncyCastle private key to a .NET private key. The X509 certificates converted fine but not the private keys. I converted the BC private key to RSACryptoServiceProvider using the provided DotNetUtilities. Unfortunately it looks like the conversion isn't complete. So I created another RSACryptoServiceProvider which I then initialized. Then I imported the private key into the one I created.

```cs
// Apparently, using DotNetUtilities to convert the private key is a little iffy. Have to do some init up front.
RSACryptoServiceProvider tempRcsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)DotNetUtilities.ToRSA((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)ackp.Private);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rcsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(1, "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider", 
            new Guid().ToString(), 
            new CryptoKeySecurity(), null));

rcsp.ImportCspBlob(tempRcsp.ExportCspBlob(true));
dotNetCert2.PrivateKey = rcsp;
```

After that, I was able to save the X509Certificate2 object directly to the key store. I didn't need the actual file so I skipped that step.

Comment: This answer was hugely helpful to me. Not sure why the DotNetUtilities conversion isn't working quite right, but this solved my problem with the same error! Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), otherwise all of the containers will have the same name (Guid.Empty), leading to the problem of keys being overwritten. At least it does if you also specify Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore on the CspParameters object. Ask me how I know!

Answer (score 7):

If you running from IIS,  ensure that the Application Pool has 'Load User Profile' set to true.
This was the only solution for me.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Previously, every time I have run into this issue, I have had to delete the cert out of my local machine cert store and re-import it. Then it all seems happy. I can't see how it could be a global permissions issue or invalid cert if simply re-importing it fixes the issue.

How I finally fixed it was using the [winhttpcertcfg](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19801) tool from the Windows Resource Kit to grant permission to the specific user that was using the cert.

The syntax would be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\winhttpcertcfg" -i cert.p12 -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -a UserWhoUsesTheCert -p passwordforp12
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue when calling a WCF REST service from .NET application where I need to attach the client certificate; All I had to do was provide access to the certificate in cert store[mmc console] to the "NETWORKSERVICE] off course my IIS Pool was default pool which indicates its using NETWORKService user account.

the mistake that I did was, I copied the cert from another store to Local
Machine -> Personnel store where the certificate was protected with password. should import the certificate explicitly in required store.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall this error but the certificate you're creating is not a valid to be used for SSL/TLS, including:

- v1 (not v3) certificate;
- missing extensions;
- invalid CN;
- ...

There are several RFC that talks about this, including [RFC5246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) on TLS (1.2).

Finally making your **own** certificates is not more *suitable* than using the ones made by `makecert` (but the last one can generate the minimum set to be usable for an SSL/TLS server certificate).

I **strongly** suggest you to buy, from a good known Certificate Authority (CA), a SSL/TLS certificate for **production**. That will get you a working certificate recognized by the most browsers and tools.

Comment: I tried changing my v1 certificate generator to a v3 version, but to no avail. Buying a certificate isn't possible for us - we are going to generate a certificate at install-time for our service. Obviously it won't have a trusted certification path, but still allows us to encrypt our data as it is transferred.

Comment: i don't suppose you could supply any more detail on what you mean by 'missing extensions' and 'invalid CN'?

Comment: That falls in the "can write a book about" (see FAQ) category ;-) You can have a **minimal** guess by looking at the internals of what `makecert` (or any SSL certificates from web sites) are made. Lots of crap around (sadly) but browsers accept them just as well.

Comment: The TLS RFC isn't concerned with how to verify a certificate. The [PKI RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280) is. There also a good note about which extensions are useful here: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tech-notes/tn3.html

Comment: For what should be in the subjectAltName or CN, check this: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error is that you ran the application / server under an account which password has changed, breaking its capability of accessing the certificate it wants to use in the certificate store.

This especially may not be as obvious if you use a NuGet package like LettuceEncrypt which automatically stores the LetsEncrypt in your store.

Delete the certificate from your store and reimport it.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this error because of a bad automation of the certificate import.

In my case, I was missing the `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` flag which indicates that the private key should be stored in the local computer store rather than in the current user store.
When this flag is omitted, current user store is used for the private key even if target certificate store is local computer store.

```
void ImportP12ToWindowsStore(string p12FilePath, string pwd)
{
    using var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    var certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    certs.Import(p12FilePath, pwd, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

    foreach (var cert in certs)
    {
        store.Add(cert);
    }
}
```