# HTTPS not working with Kestrel 3.2.187/ASPNET Core 2.1.5 running on the Service Fabric with a custom domain

Tags: azure, ssl, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, kestrel-http-server

We are running a Service Fabric application on our remote dev cluster. It consists of several stateful and stateless services and is fronted by several front-end APIs running on Kestrel.

Until now, since it was not used for production, Kestrel was configured to use a self-signed certificate, which was also used for the reverse proxy and the cluster itself and the service was running directly on the default domain provided by Azure, `<app>.<region>.cloudapp.azure.com`.

We are now getting to the point in development where the self-signed certificate errors are becoming problematic, with third party callbacks rejecting the connection, so it was seen as the time to start using a proper domain and certificate for it.

So far, I have done the following:

- Added an A record for `devcluster.somexampledomain.com` -> our public IP for the service.
- Created a Wildcard Azure Application certificate for `*.someexampledomain.com`.
- Imported the certificate to Azure Key Vault.
- Bound the certificate to the Vault Secrets of the cluster, pulling the certificate to `Cert:/LocalMachine/My/`
- Modified the application config to use this certificate when initialising Kestrel and verified that it is found when it is initialising.

  - Have tried with and without `UseHsts()` and `UseHttpsRedirection()`
  - Kestrel is configured with `Listen(IPAddress.IPv6Any, endpoint.Port, ...)` and `UseHttps(X509Certificate2)` on the options object.
  - `UseUrls(string)` is used with the default Url, which is `https://+:<port>` but tried manually adding `https://*:<port>` and even the actual hostname itself.

No matter what I have tried, no HTTPS connection can be established to the server. Trying the endpoints of the other staging servers that still use the old certificate, it works as expected.

Using `openssl s_client -connect devcluster.someexampledomain.com:<port> -prexit`, I get:

```
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
```

There are no errors or exceptions being logged on ETW, everything seems to be in order. I suspect that this might have something to do with the CN of the certificate but I have run out of ideas to try and find out what is going on and how to fix it.

Been trying to look into this using Fiddler and I am not getting much out of it, the session just ends with `fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to <myhost> (for #191) failed. System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.`

Does anybody know how to add some logging on the Kestrel side? I don't think installing Fiddler on the Azure VMs running my cluster is a viable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After delving into the Kestrel source, I found that it logs under `"Microsoft-AspNetCore-Server-Kestrel"` and `"Microsoft-Extensions-Logging"`, so adding transfer of those I found what was happening.

Connections were terminating with the following exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030D): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCHANNEL_CRED scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCHANNEL_CRED secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(X509Certificate certificate, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireServerCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint, Byte[] clientHello)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ApplyConnectionAdaptersAsync()
```

This makes it a manifestation of [Certificate problem with a new machine - credentials supplied to package not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322560/certificate-problem-with-a-new-machine-credentials-supplied-to-package-not-rec).

I spent some time trying to figure out what the best way to sort this out would be, the [Service Fabric documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint) has a script to modify the permissions but that just did not sound right.

As it turns out, this can be done directly in the ApplicationManifest as follows:

```
<Principals>
    <Users>
        <User Name="NETWORK SERVICE" AccountType="NetworkService" />
    </Users>
</Principals>
<Policies>
    <SecurityAccessPolicies>
        <SecurityAccessPolicy ResourceRef="HttpsCert2" PrincipalRef="NETWORK SERVICE" ResourceType="Certificate" />
    </SecurityAccessPolicies>
</Policies>
<Certificates>
    <SecretsCertificate X509FindValue="[HttpsCertThumbprint]" Name="HttpsCert" />
</Certificates>
```

For the `SecurityAccessPolicy` to find the `ResourceRef` it **had** to be a `SecretsCertificate`, not an `EndpointCertificate`. Since the `EndpointBindingPolicy` requires an `EndpointCertificate`, I just added both a `SecretsCertificate` and an `EndpointCertificate`, with different names. They are both referring to the same certificate, so it worked. It doesn't feel particularly clean having to double them up but that is the solution I have for now.